# MVC auto validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am making my MVC application. I created a view, in which a user picks data from dropdown list. The view is like this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@using ClassDeclarationsThsesis.Classes
@using Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities
@model ClassDeclarationsThsesis.Models.ClassesViewModel
@{    ViewBag.Title = "Classes";
}


<h2>Classes</h2>

@foreach (var user in Model.users)
{
    if (user.email.Replace(" ", String.Empty) == HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)
    {
        if (user.user_type.Replace(" ", String.Empty) == 3.ToString() || user.user_type.Replace(" ", String.Empty) == 2.ToString())
        {
            using (Html.BeginForm("Classes", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <h4>Generate summary views</h4>
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="form-group">
                    @{
                        List<SelectListItem> listItems1 = new List<SelectListItem>();
                    }
                    @foreach (var subject in Model.subject)
                    {
                        listItems1.Add(new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Text = subject.name,
                            Value = subject.name,
                        });
                    }
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.subject_name, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.subject_name, listItems1, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                            }
                        }
                        if (user.user_type.Replace(" ", String.Empty) == 1.ToString())
                        {
                            <p>You do not have enough permissions to enter this page. Contact the administrator.</p>
                                }

                            }
                        }
```

The controller is:

```
public ActionResult Classes()
{
    ClassDeclarationsDBEntities1 entities = new ClassDeclarationsDBEntities1();
    var model = new ClassesViewModel();
    model.subject = entities.Subjects.ToList();
    model.users = entities.Users.ToList();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ClassesPickGroup", "Account", new { subject_name=model.subject_name});
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

And the model:

```
    public class ClassesViewModel
    {
        public List<Subject> subject { set; get; }
        public List<User> users { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Subject")]
        public string subject_name { get; set; }

    }
```

But since the view only contains a single dropdown list, it is always Valid and redirects to different view straight away. How do I make the application wait for user choice in dropdown list and then submit the answer?

Comment: You have a form with a dropdown selector. The form isn't submitted until the user clicks submit which then executes the action. "Making the application wait for user choice" doesn't make sense. Do you have an trigger to automatically submit the form?

Comment: @Jasen there is no such trigger. And the problem is that the view is not even displayed and moves straight away to ClassesPickGroup view as in return stated.

Comment: @MaciejMiśkiewicz check the answer and test it, waitting your feedback

Comment: @Jasen this solves the problem, thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem in your view, but the problem that you create new object every time user submit and check for validation

```
public ActionResult Classes(ClassesViewModel model)
{
    ClassDeclarationsDBEntities1 entities = new ClassDeclarationsDBEntities1();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ClassesPickGroup", "Account", new {    subject_name=model.subject_name});
    }
    else {
      model.subject = entities.Subjects.ToList();
      model.users = entities.Users.ToList();
      return View(model);
    }
}
```